# Hazelcast log level flag

Tags: java, logging, hazelcast

Here is my Hazelcast deployment procedure in two steps:

1) Download the Hazelcast jar at:

`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/$HAZELCAST_VERSION/hazelcast-all-$HAZELCAST_VERSION.jar`

2) Deploy Hazelcast using the command:

```
java -server $JAVA_OPTS com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer
```

Without deviating much from the described procedure, it there a way to set the log level?

More specifically what I'm looking for is something like adding a flag similar to -Djava.util.logging.level=WARN to filter out the info logs, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

I'm trying to avoid using alternative log libraries and xml configuration files for this purpose.

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast provides multiple ways you can configure the logger. This may be helpful.

Using JVM parameter: `java -Dhazelcast.logging.type=log4j`

Using System class:    `System.setProperty( "hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j" );`

and in the log4j, add the following.

```
<logger name="com.hazelcast">
  <level value="warn" />
</logger>
```

[Logging Configuration](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Setting_Up_Clusters/Logging_Configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's more like a logging config question, rather than Hazelcast. `java.util.logging`, like other logging frameworks, uses a config file, which you can point using `java.util.logging.config.file` param. Or you create a `LogManager` and point it with `java.util.logging.config.class` param.

Hazelcast doesn't have any internal logging library, just uses `java.utl.logging`. To configure it, you need to look that logging framework's config options.